# after i click on image for blit when MOUSEBUTTONDOWN the new blit then disappear in pygame

Tags: python, image, pygame, mouse, blit

I'm new with python especially pygame and wonder how to keep my new image blit after **MOUSEBUTTONDOWN**
Here's my code:

```
color = pygame.image.load('billes.png')
red = color.subsurface(50, 70, 79, 71)
r = display.blit(red,(918,920))

def play():  
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        if r.collidepoint(pos):
            display.blit(red, (10,10))
while True:
    ...
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        ...
        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and event.button == 1:
            if r.collidepoint(pos):
                display.blit(red, (800, 700))
```

it display my new image when i ckick the left button of the mouse but disappear after one second even the button still down. I also tried to use   `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0]`     but same result.
How can I maintain the new blit after **MOUSEBUTTONDOWN**? I was thinking to put a condition with **MOUSEBUTTONUP** but I don't how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
red = (200,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
gameDisplay=pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

FPS=30
clock=pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
    cur = pygame.mouse.get_pos() #taking click events every time
    click=pygame.mouse.get_pressed() ##again, every time
    if click[0] == 1: #if left-clicked
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,red, (100,200,100,200)) #draw a red rectangle
        pygame.display.update() #and update the display


    clock.tick(FPS)
```

The problem is, you have used *pygame.display.update()* at incorrect place. 
 I have corrected it and now it's working.

> Actually this draws rectangle whenever you do left-click, but you can see only **one**
>   rectangle because they are on the same co-ordinates.

If you want to be sure about this, try:

```
import pygame,random
pygame.init()
red = (200,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
gameDisplay=pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

FPS=30
clock=pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
    cur = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click=pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if click[0] == 1:
        x=random.randint(1,700) #random coords of x
        y=random.randint(50,500) #random coords of y
        wx=random.randint(10,100) #random size of x
        hy=random.randint(60,200) #random size of y
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,red, (x,y,wx,hy)) #drawing with random variables
        pygame.display.update()


    clock.tick(FPS)
```

This shows our method is working. Also take care that if you **keep on pressing** the left-click, it'll **continue** to draw rectangles. It was drawing rectangles earlier too but we were not able to see them because they were on the same co-ordinates, that's why it seems like there is only one rectangle at that position.

> If you want to delete that rectangle, for example with right-click:

```
if click[2] == 1:
    pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay,black, (100,200,100,200))
    pygame.display.update()
```

Add this one bottom of first *if click* statement. Basically it will draw another rectangle on first rectangle,care same coords, but same color with background. So your first rectangle seems erased :-).

Comment: @JaysonGalante I edited my answer, check again please.

Comment: i tried with sprites but i still have the same problem

Comment: i forgot to check the new edited sorry i will try this

Comment: You probably doing something wrong, open a new file and copy-paste this codes. They are working. So you are doing something wrong in your program.

Comment: i tried and its working without sprites and images but when i use collidepoint it gives back the same problem

Comment: Well then don't use collidepoint, I think you can draw images with too much different ways.